# how would I make a hexagonal grid based movement system where you click to move like fallout 1 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a movement system for my game that works like fallout 1 and 2's. it would be on a hexagonal grid and the player could click on one of the hexagons and the character would take the shortest possible path to get to that hexagon. does anyone know how I could do this

I've tried using Unity's tile mapping system but I cant figure out how to make a sytem where you click on a hexagon and the player moves there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is 2D right? You can use this line to get the mouse position and convert it to a world position put this on a player script:

```
Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

then you can move the player there with:

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(mouseWorldPos.position.x - Player.position.x, mouseWorldPos.position.y - transform.position.y);
direction.Normalize();
GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().MovePosition(transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

This gets the direction between the `mouseworldpos` and the player and then uses `rigidbody` to move towards it. The speed thing can be any number you can make it a public variable to see and change it in the inspector.

This definitely isn't hexagonal, nor does it have pathfinder but you can move at least.